# does vcpkg incorrectly delivers an old version of log4cpp?

Tags: vcpkg, log4cpp

it appears to me that vcpck delivers an old version (before Jun 3, 2017) of log4cpp to me. Probably it is my fault but what could I have done wrong?

vcpkg contains log4cpp (see [here](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html)) linking to this [github repo](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/log4cpp). It appears that this is not the official log4cpp package, though, this does not seem to be really my issue.
In this repo, the file [Priority.hh](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/log4cpp/blob/master/include/log4cpp/Priority.hh) ends with

```
        static Value getPriorityValue(const std::string& priorityName);
    };
}

#endif // _LOG4CPP_PRIORITY_HH
```

When using vcpkg installing log4cpp using Clion I get a compilation error about an illegal throw statement in Priority.hh.
On my disk, this file (filename `C:\Users\ME\.clion-vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\log4cpp\Priority.hh` ends with

```
        static Value getPriorityValue(const std::string& priorityName)
    throw(std::invalid_argument);
    };
}

#endif // _LOG4CPP_PRIORITY_HH
```

The error message is:

```
C:/Users/ME/.clion-vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/log4cpp/Priority.hh:107:9: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  107 |         throw(std::invalid_argument);
      |         ^~~~~
```

As a side note, according to vcpkg, I am installing version 2.9.1#8 but the [sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4cpp/files/log4cpp-1.1.x%20%28new%29/log4cpp-1.1/) of the real log4cpp package goes up to version log4cpp-1.1.4rc3.tar.gz (released recently on 2023-03-12).
Ideally, I would like to easily install log4cpp but had problems with a pthreads dependency doing it manually...

Lastly, the [commit](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/log4cpp/commit/1b9f8f7c031d6947c7468d54bc1da4b2f414558d) removing the throw from Jun 3, 2017 is actually contained in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I created https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/31273 due to this question.

Basically I would agree that vcpkg currently packages the wrong one. Especially if checked against https://repology.org/

It isn't an outdated one but the complete wrong upstream.